# Parsing Json into JArray

Tags: c#, json

I am getting the error

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll"

When i try to parse Json data.

```
MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
JArray a = JArray.Parse(e.Result);
```

The full error

> ```
>  Error:
>  Newtonsoft.Json,JsonReaderException: Error reading JArray from JsonReader.
>  Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path ", line 1,posistion 1.
>  at
>  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Load(JsonReader reader)
>  at
>  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(String json)
>  at
>  GameStatsTrack.MainPage.dota_DownloadStringCompleted(Object senders, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
> ```

The Json data is being shown when I output it using the message box, however when I try to use the JArray it causes the program to throw the above error.

```
    {
    "result": {
        "status": 1,
        "num_results": 1,
        "total_results": 500,
        "results_remaining": 499,
        "matches": [
            {
                "match_id": 460632360,
                "match_seq_num": 419390537,
                "start_time": 1389202765,
                "lobby_type": 7,
                "players": [
                    {
                        "account_id": 52194129,
                        "player_slot": 0,
                        "hero_id": 51
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": 121480884,
                        "player_slot": 1,
                        "hero_id": 74
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": 115633024,
                        "player_slot": 2,
                        "hero_id": 54
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": 4294967295,
                        "player_slot": 3,
                        "hero_id": 47
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": 106189937,
                        "player_slot": 4,
                        "hero_id": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": 4294967295,
                        "player_slot": 128,
                        "hero_id": 30
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": 4294967295,
                        "player_slot": 129,
                        "hero_id": 89
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": 4294967295,
                        "player_slot": 130,
                        "hero_id": 25
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": 113052377,
                        "player_slot": 131,
                        "hero_id": 88
                    },
                    {
                        "account_id": 4294967295,
                        "player_slot": 132,
                        "hero_id": 48
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the JSON data? It's very hard to tell with the info you've provided. Also; what is the InnerException of the Exception that is thrown? It looks like there may be an issue with reflection but, again, hard to tell.

Comment: @Duncan Please edit your question and show full exception to allow others to help you.

Comment: edited my post to show the JSON data. It's from the steam API, Dota match histroy.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Json.Net.  You can use a service, such as http://json2csharp.com/ to generate a DTO object that you can deserialize.  After doing that, you get several classes, one of them is called `RootObject`.  You can rename this to whatever you desire.  Then you can do something like:

```
var dtoObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```

Where response is you Json in string format.  This method will give you the advantages of DTO objects, instead of dealing with `JArray`.  To access your data it would be `dtoObj.Result.Matches`.

Your other option is to use `dynamic`.

```
var dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
```

The benefit of dynamic is you don't have to maintain DTO objects, however you lose some of the enforced typing and structure.  But with dynamic you would access matches by `dynObj.result.matches`.  Sometimes with `dynamic` you have to explicitly cast it to some sort of Enumerable, which is annoying, so I prefer the DTO method above.